# Add info for multiple markers from dynamic content

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an array like this `deviceId = [005305230001JIZZZZ, 085835360001NBGJZZ, 085835360002NBGJZZ]`.

The info window should show the deviceId and be displayed based on which marker is clicked. I started looking at JavaScript only a few days back and can't understand how the functions work and dont have the time right now to learn becauseI have to get this done. I saw a few implementations on this, but I think they have done the adding multiple markers differently using functions, I think. I couldn't understand it so I used `for` loop.

The `latArray` and `lngArray` have something like this `[12.1456,12.5256,11.566]` and `[72.145,72.4557,75.23535]`

I cant figure out how to add info windows for corresponding markers.

This is the code for map:

```
function initMap() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv); 
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[0],lngArray[0]));
        map.setZoom(18);
        for(i=0;i<latArray.length;i++)
        {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[i],lngArray[i]),
                map: map,
                title:"This is the place.",
                // icon:"phone4.png" 
            }); 

            //bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());  
            console.log(latArray);
            console.log(lngArray);
        }
        //map.fitBounds(bounds);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```

How to show info window of corresponding markers.

This is content for marker:

```
contentString = '<div id = "content>' 
      +'<p style = "color:#000000">DeviceID<p>' + 
      '<p>'+ deviceId[i] + '<br></p>'  //deviceId is the array with content 
                    + '</div>'
```

I read something about closures but didn't understand. Please help

Edit: I just tried this. I'm getting `js?callback=initMap:34 InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object`

What i tried:

```
var markerArray=[];
        for(i=0;i<latArray.length;i++)
        {   
            markerArray.push("new google.maps.LatLng("+ latArray[i]+","+lngArray[i]+")");
            console.log(markerArray[i]);
        }
        console.log(markerArray[0]);
        for(i=0;i<latArray.length;i++)
        {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markerArray[i],
                map: map, 
                title:"This is the place.",
                // icon:"phone4.png" 

            }); 
           var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString[i]
                });
                marker.addListener('click', function(marker,contentString) {
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will not bother you with the explanation how closures work (as you are saying your not interested in it now), I just supply you the solution:

```js
// Your arrays with geo informations
var latArray = [-25.363, -26.263, -25.163];
var lngArray = [131.044, 131.144, 132.044];
// Your array with device information
var deviceIdArray = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"];

// Just create map according to the first geo info
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  center: {lat: latArray[0], lng: lngArray[0]},
  zoom: 6
});

// Loop throuhg all geo info
latArray.forEach(function(lat, i) {
  // For each one create info window
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div id="content>' 
              + '<p style="color:#000000">DeviceID<p>' 
              + '<p>'+ deviceIdArray[i] + '</p>'
            +'</div>' 
  });

  // For each one create marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {lat: latArray[i], lng: lngArray[i]}
  });

  // Click on the currently created marker will show the right info window
  marker.addListener("click", function() {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Hi. thanks a lot. But when creating the marker at `position: {lat: latArray[i], lng: lngArray[i]}` I got `InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`. I used `position: new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[i],lngArray[i]),` instead and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my function with map. It takes json object with some data from PHP and 'translate' it into array and then adds content to multiple markers (it is not dynamic in real time - you have to reload page). In addition it has a search box (which opens certain info window). If you don't understand do not hestitate to ask :).

```html
//check if document is fully loaded, seetting a container for ajax call results
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tablica = [];

    // ajax call for action preparing set of names, descriptions, coords and slugs needed to render deatiled markers on map
    $.ajax({
        url: 'map/json_prepare',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);


            obj.forEach(function(item, index, array)
            {
                tablica.push(item);
            });

            //call a function rendering a map itself
            var map;

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: 50.06561980, lng: 19.946850},
                zoom: 12
            });

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // LOOP ADDING MARKERS FROM DB WITH PROPER INFO WINDOWS (DESCRIPTION AND LINKS)

            // Add a markers reference
            var markers = [];

            $.each(tablica, function( key, value ) {

                //markers
                var myLatLng = {lat: value[1], lng: value[2]};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: value[0],
                    clickable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    adress: value[5]
                });

                //infowindows
                marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
                    content: '<h1>'+ value[0] + '</h1>' + '<br>' + '<br>' + value[3] + '<br>' + value[5] +'<br>' + '<br>' + '<a href="' + value[4] + '">' + 'Details' + '</a><br/>' +
                    '<a href="' + 'logged/take-part-in/' + value[4] + '">' + 'Take part in' + '</a><br>'
                });


                //eventlistener - after click infowindow opens
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    marker.info.open(map, marker);
                });


                //event listener - after dblclick zoom on certain event is set
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function() {
                    map.setZoom(18);
                    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                });



                markers.push(marker);
            });
            // End of loop adding markers from db.


            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            ///additional event listener - rightclick to get back default zoom
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function() {
                map.setZoom(12);
                map.setCenter(map.getPosition());
            });


            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            //CENTRING MAP AS ALL OF MARKERS IS VISIBLE//
            //create empty LatLngBounds object
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            for (i = 0; i < tablica.length; i++) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(tablica[i][1], tablica[i][2]),
                    map: map
                });

                //extend the bounds to include each marker's position
                bounds.extend(marker.position);
            }

            //now fit the map to the newly inclusive bounds
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///SEARCH_BOX////////
            ///Here comes part of script adding search box


            // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
            // Anchor search box and search button to the map.
            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
            var button = document.getElementById('submitSearch');
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(button);









            //replacing polish characters on order to search without necessity typing them
            function cleanUpSpecialChars(str)
            {
                str = str.replace(/[Ą]/g,"A");
                str = str.replace(/[ą]/g,"a");
                str = str.replace(/[Ę]/g,"E");
                str = str.replace(/[ę]/g,"e");
                str = str.replace(/[Ć]/g,"C");
                str = str.replace(/[ć]/g,"c");
                str = str.replace(/[Ł]/g,"L");
                str = str.replace(/[ł]/g,"l");
                str = str.replace(/[Ń]/g,"N");
                str = str.replace(/[ń]/g,"n");
                str = str.replace(/[Ó]/g,"O");
                str = str.replace(/[ó]/g,"o");
                str = str.replace(/[Ś]/g,"S");
                str = str.replace(/[ś]/g,"s");
                str = str.replace(/[Ź]/g,"Z");
                str = str.replace(/[ź]/g,"z");
                str = str.replace(/[Ż]/g,"Z");
                str = str.replace(/[ż]/g,"z");

                return str;
            }






            //Function, that search in array of markers, one which fits the key word written in searchbox.
            $('#submitSearch').click(function() {

                //Catching searched word and preparing its value for search process
                var toSearch = $(input).val().trim();
                toSearch = cleanUpSpecialChars(toSearch);
                toSearch = toSearch.toLowerCase();
                console.log('Szukana fraza -> ' + toSearch);
                var results = [];


                if (toSearch.length >=3) {


                    // Iterate through the array
                    $.each(markers, function (i, marker) {
                        //preparing certain elemnts of marker objects for search process
                        markers[i].title = cleanUpSpecialChars(markers[i].title);
                        markers[i].adress = cleanUpSpecialChars(markers[i].adress);
                        markers[i].title = markers[i].title.toLowerCase();
                        markers[i].adress = markers[i].adress.toLowerCase();

                        if (markers[i].title.indexOf(toSearch) > -1 || markers[i].adress.indexOf(toSearch) > -1) {
                            results.push(markers[i]);
                        }

                    });

                    if (results.length < 1) {
                        console.log ('nic');
                        $('#message2').slideDown(500, function () {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $('#message2').slideUp(500);
                            }, 5000);
                        });
                    }



                    // Close all the infoWindows, before rendering Search results.
                    markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                        marker.info.close(map, marker);
                    });


                    //Opens infWindows for multiple markers found and set bounds so that all markers found are visible
                    results.forEach(function (result) {
                        result.info.open(map, result);
                        bounds.extend(result.position);
                    });
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }


                else{
                    //what if user has typed less than three characters in searchbox -> render flash mess.
                    $("#message").slideDown(500, function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $("#message").slideUp(500);
                        },5000);
                    });
                }




            });
            //Enabling key Enter for triggering a search action.
            $(input).keypress(function(e){
                if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
                    $('#submitSearch').click();//Trigger search button click event
                }
            });





        },

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //obsługa błędu, jeśli nie zostanie wyświetlona mapa
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
            console.log(ajaxOptions);
            alert('Map is broken. Please try again later.')
        }

    });


});
```

It will not qork here because it doesn't contain data from php.